# How do I convert the XML input from one format to another

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery

I am having difficulties converting between 2 XML output formats. I have an input that contains a student and his/her optin flags into a service. The input looks like this:

```
<root>
    <searchCount>7</searchCount>
    <respData>
        <ferpaDeclaration>true</ferpaDeclaration>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <hsn>false</hsn>
        <gni>false</gni>
        <privacy>false</privacy>
        <gdpr>true</gdpr>
        <adv>false</adv>
        <anb>false</anb>
        <shl>false</shl>
        <grd>false</grd>
        <doc>false</doc>
    </respData>
    <respData>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <ferpaDeclaration>true</ferpaDeclaration>
        <hsn>false</hsn>
        <gni>true</gni>
        <privacy>false</privacy>
        <gdpr>true</gdpr>
        <adv>false</adv>
        <anb>true</anb>
        <shl>true</shl>
        <grd>false</grd>
        <doc>true</doc>
    </respData>
    <responseMessage>Success</responseMessage>
    <status>200</status>
</root>
```

I need to convert it to more generic output using XQuery (it's inside Informatica Cloud Real time):

```
<student-optins>
  <student-category-optin>
    <nuid>1001</nuid>
    <category>arg</category>
    <optin>false</optin>
  </student-category-optin>
  <student-category-optin>
    <nuid>1001</nuid>
    <category>ferpaDeclaration</category>
    <optin>true</optin>
  </student-category-optin>
  <student-category-optin>
    <nuid>1001</nuid>
    <category>hsn</category>
    <optin>false</optin>
  </student-category-optin>
</student-optins>
```

Comment: Where do the `category` and `optin` values come from? I cannot see any relation to the source XML...

Comment: Sorry for incomplete problem definition. Here is some clarifications.

Comment: I added the above code to the question. In the future, please add code with an edit and not as comment.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question: where do the `category` and `optin` values come from? As it is now, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I posted a clarification yesterday, but I guess it did not take. Here it is. For each group with `nuId` as primary key, I need to produce multiple repeating groups, one per category. The category corresponds to an element that has 3-letter designation, i.e. `grd, shl, anb, adv` etc. and `ferpaDeclaration`. The optin flag (`optin` element) is a value of the element with 3-digit name, for example `//root/respData/adv/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the XQuery script below. Adjust the name `source.xml` and the output at the end will be generated:

```
let $xml := for $x at $pos in doc("source.xml")/root/respData return ($x)
return
    <student-optins>
        { for $oi in $xml/*[not(self::nuId)] return 
            element {'student-category-optin'}
            {
                $oi/../nuId,
                element {'category'}
                {
                    local-name($oi)
                },
                element {'optin'}
                {
                    $oi/text()
                }
            }
        }
    </student-optins>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student-optins>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>ferpaDeclaration</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>hsn</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>gni</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>privacy</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>gdpr</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>adv</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>anb</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>shl</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>grd</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1002</nuId>
        <category>doc</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>ferpaDeclaration</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>hsn</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>gni</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>privacy</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>gdpr</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>adv</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>anb</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>shl</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>grd</category>
        <optin>false</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
    <student-category-optin>
        <nuId>1001</nuId>
        <category>doc</category>
        <optin>true</optin>
    </student-category-optin>
</student-optins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the input is assigned to $myInput, your xQuery may look like this.

If you need the output sorted, you can do orderby.

```
 {
   <student-optins>
    for $x in $myInput//respData
    return  
    <student-category-optin> 
    <nuid>{$x/nuid} </nuid> 
     <category>{$x/category}</category> 
    <optin>{$x/optin}</optin> 
    </student-category-optin>
}
```